# Why are the brake temperatures so high during the cruise?

Tags: airbus-a320, braking, temperature

While monitoring the A320 aircraft systems during cruise I noticed that brake temperatures are relatively high compared to the OAT. I have seen brake temperature indications range between 20°C and 120°C during the cruise, when the OAT is generally around -55°C.

I would have always assumed that the brake temperatures would naturally cool down, but even hours into a flight brake temperatures are consistently high compared to OAT. Is there any reason for this? I haven't been able to find any answer on the FCOM or FCTM.

Comment: See also: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33028/3159

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The brakes will be above ambient temperature of the departure airport due to the braking action during taxing.
While airborn there is little airflow to cool down the brakes, so this temperature will only drop of slowly. Plus the wheel-´well houses many different systems (hydraulics, also the packs are close by) adding heat and thus slowing and even stopping the cooling.